# Tabla de multiplicar con 3 intentos de acertar y nota final

Tags: java, bucles

Estoy empezando con Java y tras haber echado un rato largo no sé como programar este problema, este es el anunciado:

Crea una aplicación que solicite al usuario un valor numérico comprendido entre 1 y 10. Después la aplicación debe ir preguntándole al usuario la tabla de múltiplicar.

Si el usuario se equivoca en un resultado, la aplicación indicará un mensaje de error y volverá a solicitarle el resultado de la operación. Si el usuario no acierta a la tercera vez se contabiliza un error, se le muestra el resultado de la operación y se le pregunta la siguiente operación.

Al final la aplicación debe mostrar el resultado de la prueba en función del número de errores del usuario:

- INS  Si el usuario falló más de 5 veces.
- SUF  Si el usuario fallo 4 veces.
- BIEN si el usuario falló entre 2 o 3 veces.
- NOT Si falló una vez.
- SOB  Si no tuvo ningún error.

  import java.util.Scanner;

  public class Ejercicio7_Bucles {

  ```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int resultado;
        int numero;
        int nota=0;
        int error=0;

        Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Dame un numero : ");
        numero=entrada.nextInt();

        int i=0;
        for(i=0;i<11;i++){
            System.out.println(numero + " * " + i + " = " );
            resultado=entrada.nextInt();
            if(resultado==numero*i) {
                System.out.println(" El resultado es correcto ");
            }else{
                int j=0;
                do{ 
                    j++; 
                    System.out.println("El resultado introducido es erroneo, vuelve a intentarlo ");
                    resultado=entrada.nextInt();
                } while (resultado == numero * i || j >= 3);
                if (resultado == numero * i) {
                    System.out.println(" El resultado es correcto ");   
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println(" Has gastado las 3 oportunidades ");
                    error = error + 1;
                }
            }
        }

        switch(nota) {
        case 0:{
            if(error==0) {
                System.out.println(" Has cometido " + error + " tu nota es de SOBRESALIENTE");
            }
        };break;
        case 1:{
            if(error==1) {
            System.out.println(" Has cometido " + error + " tu nota es de NOTABLE");
            }
        };break;

        case 2:{
            if(error==2 || error==3) {
                System.out.println(" Has cometido " + error + " tu nota es de BIEN");
            }
        };break;

        case 3:{
            if(error==4) {
                System.out.println(" Has cometido " + error + " tu nota es de SUFICIENTE");
            }
        };break;

        case 4:{
            if(error>=5) {
                System.out.println(" Has cometido " + error + " tu nota es de SUSPENSO");
            }
        };break;

    }
  ```

  }

}

Comment: Y cual es el problema?

Comment: Por una parte, ya sé que debería declarar métodos de mutación ,etc. Pero el tema es que estamos empezando desde 0. En el bucle de los tres intentos de responder bien , si respondo bien el segundo intento no se lo traga y hasta que corre los tres intentos no salto al siguiente número. Y no me contabiliza ni los errores ni me dice la nota final.

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez te sirva hacerlo con métodos estáticos. Sólo sustituye el Teclado.leeInt() por el Scanner...
Si no han visto métodos, te recomiendo que le eches un ojo al código y te fijes sobretodo en el switch, ya que tu implementación me deja muchas dudas...

```
public class Ejercicio7_Bucles {
    
    public static int intentoUsuario(int base, int multiplicador) {
        int erroresIntento = 0;
        for(int i=1; i<=3; i++) {
            System.out.print("Intento[" + i + "]: " + base + "x" + multiplicador + " = ");
            if(Teclado.leeInt() == (base*multiplicador)) {
                System.out.println();
                return erroresIntento;
            } else {
                erroresIntento++;
                if(i==3) {
                    System.out.println("El resultado ingresado es incorrecto. Siguiente multiplicador.\n");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("El resultado ingresado es incorrecto. Intente nuevamente.");
                }
            }
        }
        
        return erroresIntento;
    }
    
    public static void imprimirTabla(int base) {
        for(int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
            System.out.println(base + " x " + i + " = " + (base*i));
        }
    }
    
    public static String nota(int numErrores) {
        String notaFinal;
        switch(numErrores) {
        case 0:
            notaFinal = "Sobresaliente. No has cometido errores";
            break;
        case 1:
            notaFinal = "Notable. Sólo has cometido 1 error";
            break;
        case 2:
        case 3:
            notaFinal = "Bien. Tuviste " + numErrores + " errores. Puedes mejorar.";
            break;
        case 4:
            notaFinal = "Suficiente. Tuviste 4 errores. Puedes mejorar";
            break;
        default:
            notaFinal = "Insuficiente. Tuviste " + numErrores + " errores. Sigue tratando.";
        }
        return notaFinal;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numero, erroresTotales=0;
        System.out.print("Ingresa el número cuya tabla se validará: ");
        numero = Teclado.leeInt();
        for(int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
            erroresTotales += intentoUsuario(numero, i);
        }
        System.out.println( nota(erroresTotales) );
        System.out.println( "\nLa tabla completa es:" );
        imprimirTabla(numero);
    }

}
```

Notas:

- El método intentoUsuario recibe la base y el multiplicador. Inicializa una variable erroresIntento en cero y solicita el intento al usuario. Si el usuario acierta, devuelve el número de errores que haya cometido (como máximo, 3 que es las veces que se repite el ciclo)
- El método imprimir tabla, imprime la tabla de multiplicar del número que reciba como parámetro...
- El método nota recibe el número de errores totales que se hayan cometido y devuelve el String que debe aparecer como nota. Nótese el uso del default y que entre el caso 2 y 3 no hay break, por lo que el caso 2 "se sigue" y ejecuta el código del caso 3.
- En el método main sólo se requiere saber el número del que se va a calcular la tabla y los errores totales. Para cada número de la tabla se manda a llamar el intento del usuario, y se actualiza el valor de erroresTotales (Operador +=). Al final, se imprime la nota correspondiente y la tabla...
  Ojalá te sirva

Comment: Muchas gracias @Agro88. Infinitamente agradecido por tu respuesta.